# can upload photos from local drive to my iphone desktop simulation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I would like to import some photos from my mac desktop to my iphone app simulation. i would like to give the path of my desktop in my app simulation and collect photos from there. Can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Simulator is a sandboxed environment. The simulator does provide a sample photo library and sample photos for apps to integrate with, however. How are these not suitable for your use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can access iOS Simulator's store at

> ~/Application Support/iPhone Simulator

(where the tilde represents your home folder).

Maybe you could create an alias in your application's sandbox and access. iOS supports traversal of HFS+ symlinks. (Although I haven't tried as of today.)

By the way, I don't think there's a way to add photos to the simulator's Photos app. At least not with the above method.